# Azure Logic App: how to make a x-www-form-encoded?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to make a request with *Content-Type x-www-form-urlencoded* that works perfectly in postman but does not work in Azure Logic App I receive a Bad Request response for missing parameters, like I'd not send enything.

I'm using the Http action.

The body value is param1=value1&param2=value2, but I tried other formats.

Comment: Can you post the JSON code of your Logic App? 
Have you tried sending the request to https://requestb.in/ to inspect how the Logic App is sending the body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the body needs to be:

```
{  param1=value1&param2=value2 }
```

(i.e. surround with {})

That said, value1 and value2 should be url encoded. If they are a simple string (e..g a_b) then this would be find as is but if it is for exmaple https://a.b it should be converted to https%3A%2F%2Fa.b

The easiest way I found to do this is to use https://www.urlencoder.org/ to convert it. convert each param separately and put the converted value instead of the original one.

Answer (score 6):

```
Try out the below solution . Its working for me .

concat(
'grant_type=',encodeUriComponent('authorization_code'),
'&client_id=',encodeUriComponent('xxx'),
'&client_secret=',encodeUriComponent('xxx'),
'&redirect_uri=',encodeUriComponent('xxx'),
'&scope=',encodeUriComponent('xxx'),
'&code=',encodeUriComponent(triggerOutputs()['relativePathParameters']['code'])).

Here code is dynamic parameter coming from the previous flow's query parameter.

NOTE : **Do not forget to specify in header as Content-Type ->>>> application/x-www-form-urlencoded**
```

Answer (score 6):

```
HTTP Method: POST
URI : https://xxx/oauth2/token
```

In Headers section, add the below content-type:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

And in the Body, add:

```
grant_type=xxx&client_id=xxx&resource=xxx&client_secret=xxx
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation to your answer please?

Comment: The best solution worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Answering this one, as I needed to make a call like this myself, today.
As Assaf mentions above, the request indeed has to be urlEncoded and a lot of times you want to compose the actual message payload.

Also, make sure to add the `Content-Type` header in the HTTP action with value `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

therefore, you can use the following code to combine variables that get urlEncoded:

```
concat('token=', **encodeUriComponent**(body('ApplicationToken')?['value']),'&user=', **encodeUriComponent**(body('UserToken')?['value']),'&title=Stock+Order+Status+Changed&message=to+do')
```

When using the concat function (in composing), the curly braces are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the screenshot from the solution that works for me, I hope it will be helpful. This is example with Microsoft Graph API but will work with any other scenario:

[image]