# how to send a Request's parameter using HTTP tool in Logic app

Tags: json, postman, httprequest, azure-logic-apps, x-www-form-urlencoded

I'm trying to send a request using HTTP tool as you can see

[image]

but i get this error:

> {
> "error": "invalid_request",
> "error_description": "AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.\r\nTrace ID: -e540--94fd-\r\nCorrelation ID: -0b33--8557-\r\nTimestamp: 2022-08-18 11:25:43Z",
> "error_codes": [
> 900144
> ],

although i can achieve this using Postman but i don't know if i'm using it the right way.
and because it's in ***x-www-form-urlencoded*** format i can't just paste it in Body, i guess it has to be in Json format to be used in Body.

[image]

how can should use this values in HTTP tool of Logic App?

Comment: i found the answer [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45554887/azure-logic-app-how-to-make-a-x-www-form-encoded?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45554887/azure-logic-app-how-to-make-a-x-www-form-encoded?rq=1). you just need to add in the header section:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

and in the body your `x-www-form-urlencoded` foramated string.